# How to randomly select cell and the adjacent cell on excel

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to find a formula on excel that will allow me to randomly select a cell between a range (this part I have found a formula for) and have the value pasted into another cell AND then have the cell next to the randomly selected cell's value also selected and pasted into a different cell.

Not sure if this makes sense so I will explain what I'm trying to do.

I have a column full of years and the adjacent column full of prices that correspond to each year. I want a year randomly selected and pasted into a cell lower down on the spreadsheet, and I want the corresponding price for this randomly selected year pasted next to this cell.

Thank you in advance!

Anna

Answer (score 1):

Say the data is in **A1** through **B10**

In **D1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A1:A10,RANDBETWEEN(1,10))
```

and in **E1** enter:

```
=VLOOKUP(D1,A1:B10,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Another approach is to enter:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,10)
=INDIRECT("A" & C1)
=INDIRECT("B" & C1)
```

In **C1** through **E1**

*(Either approach will work if column **A** contains years rather than names)*

Yet another approach is to enter:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,10)
=INDEX(A1:A10,C1)
=INDEX(B1:B10,C1)
```

In **C1** through **E1**